# Creating SQLite View Statement

Tags: qt, sqlite

I am trying to port my DB structure from SQL Server to SQLite for offline usability.  Need help figuring out why this returns an error.  I am using Qt QSQLITE driver to send this so my error feedback is minimal:"No query Unable to fetch row".

```
CREATE VIEW [IF NOT EXISTS] viewName 
AS 
      SELECT T1.*, T2.* FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID WHERE 
      (T1.Finished = 0);
```

I will add that the T1.finished is of type boolean.  I have queried the db and both tables do exist.  In addition the IDs are of type integer and when i created the table said "primary key autoincrement".

Thanks

-MrShawn

Comment: Show the exact code you're using to execute this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS viewName 
AS 
      SELECT T1.*, T2.* FROM T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID WHERE 
      (T1.Finished = 0);
```

Enclosing in `[ ]` makes the enclosed value an identifier and thus `IF NOT EXISTS` are then not keywords.

Comment: Mike, Thanks a lot I feel silly that the problem was so simple. :)